# Does analytic closed form solution exist for this trigonometric equation?

Tags: trigonometry

solve for x: $\sin(ax)=k\sin(bx)$, a,b,k and x are real numbers

I am looking for a very general solution when a,b and k are completely unrelated.

Comment: What if a,b,k are rational numbers?

Answer (score 3):

**No**. There isn't one in general. Not unless you consider the following infinitely-nested expression acceptable: $$x=\frac1a\arcsin\left(k\sin\left(\frac ba\arcsin\left(k\sin\left(\frac ba\arcsin\left(k\sin\left(\frac ba\arcsin\left(k\sin\left(\ldots\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)\right)$$

Comment: That's a cute expression you have there. If you could provide a hint as to one goes about obtaining it, I would be most grateful. :)

Comment: @DavidH: Just apply $\arcsin$ to both sides of the original equation, divide through *a*, and then replace *x* recursively.

Comment: That's so much easier to understand than I was expecting. Thanks.